# Make jQuery Wait For $.post to complete updating page

Tags: jquery, function, .post

I am calling a function to refresh a part of the current page with a jQuery.post - and then after that function completes I need to execute another function that updates the Google Map on that page, using the updated HTML written out from the $.post

I cannot nest the functions because DoGoogleMap() won't work within the scope of the RefreshSubdivisionList() function.

How do I make it wait for the $.post to finish writing the updated HTML to the page before it calls the DoGoogleMap() function?

```
function RefreshSubdivisionList() {

    var formActionScript = jQuery("#RefreshSubdivisionForm").attr('action');

    jQuery.post(formActionScript, jQuery("#RefreshSubdivisionForm").serialize()).done(function(data) {

        jQuery(".subdivision-list").html(data).show();

    }, 'text');

    return true;

}


jQuery("#RefreshSubdivisionForm").submit(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery.when( RefreshSubdivisionList() ).done(function(){
        jQuery('#map_canvas').gmap('destroy');
        DoGoogleMap();
    });

    return false;

});
```

Answer (score 1):

**[jQuery.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)** provides mechanisms to deal with the case of synchronizing multiple **async** calls. Take a look:

```
function ajax1 {
    return $.ajax("/page1/action", {});
}

function ajax2 {
    return $.ajax("/page2/action", {});
}

var promise = $.when(ajax1, ajax2);

promise.done(function (resp1, resp2) {
  // The parameters resp1 and resp2 are the responses 
  // of their respective ajax1 and ajax2 calls.
  // Each parameter is an array that contains the ajax response
  // with the following signature:
  // [data, statusText, jqXHR]
  // See: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jqXHR

  // suppose the data response for ajax1 is: "Hello"
  // suppose the data response for ajax2 is: "world"
  var data = resp1[0] + " " + resp2[0];

  if ((/hello\sworld/i).test(data)) {
    console.info("Promises rules!");
  }
});
```

In the previous example we handle **success** responses, but in the same way we can handle **failure** responses.

The [jqXHR](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) object returned by [jQuery.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) implement the **Promise interface**, giving them all the properties, methods, and behavior of a **[Promise](https://api.jquery.com/Types/#Promise)** (see [Deferred object](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) for more information)

Other way is to create [deferred](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) objects, and resolve each deferred object with the expected result and finally, unify the resolved responses:

```
var d1 = $.Deferred();
var d2 = $.Deferred();

$.when(d1, d2).done(function (resp1, resp2) {
    console.log(resp1); // "Fish"
    console.log(resp2); // "Pizza"
});

d1.resolve("Fish");
d2.resolve("Pizza");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place `DoGoogleMap();` directly in `done` callback of `post`, can't you?

Then it will load your maps one the post is completed.

Comment: It didn't work when I tried it initially, but now it seems to be.  I figured there was a scope issue running that function inside the other, but it's working fine now.  Odd.  

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To make this work it looks like all you need to do is return the jqXHR object from the `RefreshSubdivisionList` method.

jQuery gives XHR requests like `post` the `deffered` interface which is what the `when` method uses to determine the state of the request. If it's done or failed, etc.

```
function RefreshSubdivisionList() {
    var formActionScript = jQuery("#RefreshSubdivisionForm").attr('action');

    var postObj = jQuery.post(formActionScript, jQuery("#RefreshSubdivisionForm").serialize());

    postObj.done(function(data) {
        jQuery(".subdivision-list").html(data).show();
    }, 'text');

    return postObj;
}


jQuery("#RefreshSubdivisionForm").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery.when( RefreshSubdivisionList() ).done(function(){
        jQuery('#map_canvas').gmap('destroy');
        DoGoogleMap();
    });

    return false;

});
```